# bash and awk script get to previous month date in format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I need to get last month date in format YYYY-MM-DD, suppose if run script in May on any date then it should return me Last date of April month in format 2018-04-30.

```
Would be good if can get the same work done with awk statement also.
```

I tried below code and able to get output in below form but i need in format YYYY-MM-DD

```
Apr 30 2018
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cur_month=`date +%m`
cur_year=`date +%Y`
prev_month=$(($cur_month-1))

# Check to see if this is January
if [ $prev_month -lt 1 ]
then
prev_year=$(($cur_year-1))
prev_month=12
LastDayOfpreviousMonth=`cal $prev_month $cur_year | grep -v "^$" | sed -n  '1p;$p' | tr "\n" " "  | awk '{print substr($1,1,3),$NF,$2}'`
else
LastDayOfpreviousMonth=`cal $prev_month $cur_year | grep -v "^$" | sed -n  '1p;$p' | tr "\n" " "  | awk '{print substr($1,1,3),$NF,$2}'`
fi
echo $LastDayOfpreviousMonth
```

Input file: In this file in column14 need to put value of date for last month in form YYYY-MM-DD(2018-04-30)

```
EPOS|EPOS_OUTWARD_B2B_OSR_TTML_TTSL_$LDPM_20180504_V1.0.txt|||AD|Outward|ANP|Receipt cum invoice|42018|37AAACT2438A1ZS|INV|TAX|IN37201800001452|2018-04-17||||1||||SOHANRAJ RAJ KUMAR||||37||||||9984||Telecommunication services||||300|0||9|27|9|27|||||354||||||||||
EPOS|EPOS_OUTWARD_B2B_OSR_TTML_TTSL_$LDPM_20180504_V1.0.txt|||AD|Outward|ANP|Receipt cum invoice|42018|37AAACT2438A1ZS|INV|TAX|IN37201800001426|2018-04-12||||1||||MOLLITE SIVARAMA KRISHNA||||37||||||9984||Telecommunication services||||300|0||9|27|9|27|||||354||||||||||
EPOS|EPOS_OUTWARD_B2B_OSR_TTML_TTSL_$LDPM_20180504_V1.0.txt|||GJ|Outward|GUJ|Receipt cum invoice|42018|24AAACT2438A1ZZ|INV|TAX|IN24201800000651|2018-04-07||||1||||AIREN LTD ||||24||||||9984||Telecommunication services||||500|0||9|45|9|45|||||590||||||||||
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is evident that the OP's dateformat is unix based, it is worth mentioning that there are two general calendars in play. The [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) and the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). Both calendars have a different concept of what a leap year is.

**note:** at this time, most countries [adopt the Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar). However, it was not at once officially adopted by all countries. This should be kept in mind when making historical research. In Great Britain, for instance , the change was made as late as in A.D. 1752, and in Turkey not before 1927. *(Ref Astronomical Algorithms by Jean Meeus)*

With this in mind, and depending whether your digital file is from Turkey from 1920 or 2011 or Great Britain from 1740 or 1789, I present two `awk` solutions

In a leap year, the month February has 29 days, where in a common year it has 28 days.

In the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar), a year is a leap (or bissextile) year of 366 days if its numerical designation is divisible by 4. All other years are common years (365 days).

Using `awk`, as this was the OP's request, we can write the following function that would do the requested conversion :

```
awk 'function julian(str,    y,m,d) {
         y=substr(str,1,4); m=substr(str,6,2)+0;
         if (m==1) {y=y-1; m=12} else {m=m-1}
         if (((m-1)%7)%2==0) {d=31} else {d=30}
         if (m==2) { d = (y%4==0) ? 29 : 28 }
         return sprintf("%0.4d-%0.2d-%0.2d",y,m,d)
      }
      { print $14, julian($14) }' <file>
```

In the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), the same rule holds as in the Julian calendar, with the following exception: the centurial years that are not divisible by 400 are common years.

```
awk 'function gregorian(str,    y,m,d) {
         y=substr(str,1,4); m=substr(str,6,2)+0;
         if (m==1) {y=y-1; m=12} else {m=m-1}
         if (((m-1)%7)%2==0) {d=31} else {d=30}
         if (m==2) { d = (y%4!=0) ? 28 : (y%100==0 && y%400!=0 ?  28 : 29 ) }
         return sprintf("%0.4d-%0.2d-%0.2d",y,m,d)
      }
      { print $14, gregorian($14) }' <file>
```

As the UNIX calendar is Gregorian, we can also use the [GNU Awk Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html). This however will only work from 1970-02-01 till 2038-01-19 for 32-bit systems and 292277026596-04-01 for 64-bit systems (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem))

```
awk 'function unix(str,    tmp) {
        tmp=substr(str,1,7)" 01 00 00 00"; gsub("-"," ",tmp);
        return strftime("%Y-%m-%d",mktime(tmp) - 1) }
     { print $14, unix($14) }' <file>
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU date itself is capable of handling this task perfectly and reliably, no need for other magic.

```
$ date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) - 1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d"
2018-04-30
```

Comment: Hi @Inian - How can i run this same command inside awk, because insise awk i believe this command will give error.

Comment: @as7951: You don't need to use `awk`, just use the above command in your shell script